# Glide not creating cache directions on Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-glide, image-loading

How does Glide caching work with android M . I'm unable to see the cache directory in my external storage. I understand that this would need an external storage permission, but post permission how does reinitialization of the external cache work.

Here is my GlideModule

```
public class GlideDefaultModule implements GlideModule {

    private static GlideDefaultModule glideDefaultModule;

    private GlideBuilder glideBuilder;

    public static GlideDefaultModule getModule() {
        return glideDefaultModule;
    }


    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        glideDefaultModule = this;
        this.glideBuilder = builder;

        MemorySizeCalculator calculator = new MemorySizeCalculator(context);
        int defaultMemoryCacheSize = calculator.getMemoryCacheSize();

        int cutOff = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 6f); // 16% of total memory for bitmaps

        if (cutOff < 0 || cutOff > defaultMemoryCacheSize) {

            cutOff = defaultMemoryCacheSize;
        }

        builder.setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(cutOff));
        builder.setBitmapPool(new LruBitmapPool(cutOff));

        Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        if (BaseUtil.isSDCardAvailable()) {
            builder.setDiskCache(
                    new DiskLruCacheFactory(new DiskLruCacheFactory.CacheDirectoryGetter() {
                        @Override
                        public File getCacheDirectory() {
                            return createDirectoryIfNeeded();
                        }
                    }
                            , BaseConstants.DISK_CACHE_SIZE));
        } else {
            builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, BaseConstants.DISK_CACHE_SIZE / 10));
        }


    }

    public File createDirectoryIfNeeded() {

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + BaseConstants.PIC_DIRECTORY);
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        return folder;


    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {

    }

    public GlideBuilder getGlideBuilder() {
        return glideBuilder;
    }
}
```

Ps: This was working fine until marshmallow I targeted marshmallow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After interacting [with Glide developers](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1333), I decided to implement a strategy where in I check for availability of the storage permission with each request and depending on the provision of the same I choose whether to use `diskCacheStrategy` to `NONE`or `ALL`.

This seems to be graceful way to tradeoff between network usage and storage.

An alternative would be to write your own `LruDiskCacheFactory` which is permission aware.